# How convet type date to long using Talend

Tags: talend

I want to convert type date to long in Talend

[image]

And this is an exemple of error

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Could you add an example of the expected result ? problem is not clear as it is stated.

Comment: @Corentin can you help please. Thank you

Comment: Sorry but you are not giving the expected result ! For a date like 2020-08-04 14:23:00, what is the result you want to achieve ?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that `row7.EVENT_TIME` is a Date.

If you really want a `java.sql.Timestamp` then

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(row7.EVENT_TIME.getTime())
```

or if you simply want a `long` then

```
row7.EVENT_TIME.getTime()
```